# Multi-VM Vagrantfile with shared chef settings but different roles

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra

I'm trying to use a single Vagrantfile to define 2 VMs with different Chef roles, and I'd like to share certain chef configuration betweeen both vms, but specify the runlist, environment, and attributes seperately.  Is there a way I can do this without duplicating the common settings?

For instance, if I did something like:

```
# Development system
config.vm.define "dev", primary: true do |dev|
  dev.vm.hostname = "server1"
  dev.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.name = "server1"
  end

  dev.vm.provision "chef_client" do |chef|
    chef.run_list = [ "role[dev-system]" ]
    chef.environment = "development"
    chef.json = {
      "key" => "value1"
    }
  end
end

# Production system
config.vm.define "pro", primary: true do |pro|
  pro.vm.hostname = "server2"
  pro.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.name = "server2"
  end

  pro.vm.provision "chef_client" do |chef|
    chef.run_list = [ "role[pro-system]" ]
    chef.environment = "production"
    chef.json = {
      "key" => "value2"
    }
  end
end

config.vm.provision "chef_client" do |chef|
  chef.chef_server_url = "https://example.com/organizations/tsrd"
  chef.validation_key_path = "~/my-validator.pem"
  chef.validation_client_name = "my-validator"
  chef.delete_node = true
  chef.delete_client = true
  # ... PLUS OTHER COMMON CONFIGURATIONS...
end
```

Would it apply the individual chef sections for each vm along with the shared section, or just override the first sections with the last? If not, is there an easier way to do this? Perhaps a wrapper function that is called inside each vm definition block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose I took another way.

I define my vms as a hash in the vagrant file like this:

```
machinesBases = {
  'srv0643' => { 
    'ip_address' => '172.30.0.140',
    'env' => 'Z1', 
    'alias' => 'z1frnessus01',
    'roles' => ['nessus'],
    'additionnal_recipes' => ['java']
  },
  'srv0683' => {
    'ip_address' => '172.30.0.51',
    'env' => 'P1', 
    'alias' => 'p1frkegin01',
    'roles' => [],
    'additionnal_recipes' => ['kegin_cookbook']
  } 
}
```

And then I loop over it, using the hash values

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  machinesBases.each do |hostname,properties|
    config.vm.define hostname do |box|
      box.vm.hostname = "#{hostname}.my.domain.org"

      box.vm.network :private_network, ip: properties["ip_address"]

      box.vm.provision :chef_client do |chef|
        chef.chef_server_url = CHEF_CHEF_SERVER_URL
        chef.validation_key_path = CHEF_VALIDATION_KEY_PATH
        chef.environment = properties["env"]
         chef.add_recipe "base-linux"
        properties['roles'].each do |role|
          chef.add_role role
        end
        properties['additionnal_recipes'].each do |recipe|
          chef.add_recipe recipe
        end
      end
    end
  end unless machinesBases.length == 0
end
```

I stripped some parts of the vagrant file (constant definition for exemple) to avoid being too long here, but I think you got the idea.

This is perhaps not the best way, but I found it quite easy to extend/update.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could just add the two machines to an array and then loop over the array and add the common elements within the loop.

```
a = config.vm.define "dev", primary: true do |dev|
...
end

b = config.vm.define "pro", primary: true do |pro|
...
end

[a, b].each do |next_vm|
  next_vm.provision "chef_client" do |chef|
    chef.chef_server_url = "https://example.com/organizations/tsrd"
    chef.validation_key_path = "~/my-validator.pem"
    chef.validation_client_name = "my-validator"
    chef.delete_node = true
    chef.delete_client = true
    # ... PLUS OTHER COMMON CONFIGURATIONS...
  end
end
```